# Inserting Row in Missing Hourly Data in R using padr package - weird error

Tags: r, padr

I am new to R and I am having some issues with the padr package described [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/padr/padr.pdf).

I have a hourly data set that is missing hours and I would like to insert a row to input a value for the missing data. I am trying to use the pad function and the fill_by_value function from the padr package but I am getting an error when I use the pad function.

The data called Mendo is presented as:

```
Date.Local    Time.Local    Sample.Measurement
2016-01-01    00:00:00                      3
2016-01-01    00:01:00                      4
2016-01-01    00:02:00                      1
2016-01-01    00:04:00                      4
2016-01-01    00:05:00                      5
```

I want the final data to look like:

```
Date.Local    Time.Local    Sample.Measurement
2016-01-01    00:00:00                      3
2016-01-01    00:01:00                      4
2016-01-01    00:02:00                      1
2016-01-01    00:03:00                    999
2016-01-01    00:04:00                      4
2016-01-01    00:05:00                      5
```

I am under the impression the padr packaged wants a datetime POSIXct column so I use the command

```
Mendo$Time.Local <- as.POSIXct(paste(Mendo$Date.Local, Mendo$Time.Local), format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
```

to get:

```
Time.Local             Sample.Measurement
2016-01-01 00:00:00                      3
2016-01-01 00:01:00                      4
2016-01-01 00:02:00                      1
2016-01-01 00:04:00                      4
2016-01-01 00:05:00                      5
```

Now I try to use the pad function like instruction in the link provided above. My line of code is:

```
Mendo_padded <- Mendo %>% pad
```

and I get the error:

> Error in if (total_invalid == nrow(x)) { : 
>     missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
>   In addition: Warning message:
>   In if (unique(nchar(x_char)) == 10) { :
>     the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

If this were to work, I would then use the command

```
Mendo_padded %>% fill_by_value(Sample.Measurement, value = 999)
```

to get all the missing hours Sample.Measurement value to be 999.

I would love feedback, suggestions or comments on what I may be doing wrong and how I can go about getting this code to work! Thank you!

Comment: I ran your code without any problem. Can you specify more on your dataset?

Comment: The data I presented comes from a much larger data set that is hourly PM10 concentration from the EPA found [here](https://aqsdr1.epa.gov/aqsweb/aqstmp/airdata/download_files.html#Raw). I open the file in R using the read.csv file and then grab a selection of rows from the data where the County is Mendocino. Then from there I combine the local date and time columns using the POSIXct function. Then finally I removed all the columns but the datetime column and the sample measurement column.

Comment: The code I explained in my previous comment is: `PM10 <- read.csv(file="~/Downloads/hourly_81102_2016.csv")`
`Mendo <- PM10[PM10$County.Name == "Mendocino",]`
`Mendo$Time.Local <- as.POSIXct(paste(Mendo$Date.Local, Mendo$Time.Local), format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')`
`Mendo <- Mendo[,c(11,14)]`

Comment: I added the inputs to the pad function making the line of code now: `Mendo_padded <- Mendo %>% pad(Mendo$Time.Local, interval = 'hour', start_val = NULL, end_val = NULL, group = NULL, break_above = 1)` and now I am getting this error:
`Error in as.POSIXlt.character(x, tz, ...) : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format`

Comment: Which version of `padr` are you running? This is a bug that should be fixed in the latest version 0.3.0.

Comment: I am using the 0.3.0 version for OS X El Captain.

Comment: Then I am afraid you have hit another bug. Would you mind sharing a dataset with me that produces the issue on your system? You can do that at https://github.com/EdwinTh/padr/issues/33

Comment: No problem. I have uploaded it to the github page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that `pad` can automatically detect which column is of Date / POSIXct / POSIXlt type, so you do not need to supply `Mendo$Time.Local` to `pad`. The padding will be applied on hour intervals.

```
library(magrittr)
library(padr)

PM10 <- read.csv(file="../Downloads/hourly_81102_2016.csv",
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE) # don't change the columns to factors
Mendo <- PM10[PM10$County.Name == "Mendocino",]
Mendo$Time.Local <-
  as.POSIXct(paste(
    Mendo$Date.Local, Mendo$Time.Local), format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
Mendo <- Mendo[,c("Time.Local", "Sample.Measurement")]


# remove Mendo$Time.Local
Mendo_padded <- Mendo %>% na.omit %>%
  pad(interval = 'hour', 
      start_val = NULL, end_val = NULL, group = NULL, 
      break_above = 1)
```

You may also consider using the column `Time.GMT` and `Date.GMT` because date and time may depend on where you (your computer) are.

**Edit:** As suggested by OP, `na.omit` should be used before `pad` to avoid NA values in the Date column.

Comment: This format results in the orginal error I showed above of `Error in if (total_invalid == nrow(x)) { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
In addition: Warning message:
In if (unique(nchar(x_char)) == 10) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used`

Comment: I deliberately assign an NA in an element of ````Mendo$Time.Local```` and reproduce the same error. Is this your situation? If so I think you may report a bug on github.

Comment: Raymkchow, there was an NA sometimes in my Mendo$Time.Local and this was producing the error. Thank you so much for the help! I was able to remove it with the `na.omit(Mendo)` command and then the pad function worked! Thank you so much!